# Lexicographically k-th small string

Tags: algorithms, strings, permutations

The origin problem is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1984522/lexicographically-kth-small-string). Now it is deleted.

Suppose I have 3 'available' copies of `a`, 2 of `b`, 3 of `c`, and 4 of `d`.

1. I want to know the number of different strings with length $l$ using these characters (but no more than the available copies).
2. Is there an efficient (i.e. $o(k)$) algorithm for computing the $k$-th smallest string of length $l$ in lexicographic order?

For example, The first string of length 1 is `a`, the second string of length 3 is `aab`, the 5th string of length 5 is `aaacc` (following `aaabb`, `aaabc`, `aaabd`, and `aaacb`), etc.

What kind of algorithm or math can I use to calculate?

Comment: Please do not cross-post. If you have decided to move your question from Math it should be migrated or doing so manually you should delete the previous one.

Comment: It's midnight in China, I will close the origin problem at math tomorrow.
By the way, k=1 the answer is 4, k=2 the answer is 16, k=3 the answer is 63(except bbb).

Comment: @Evil It certainly shouldn't be `$k-th$`, since that denotes the difference between $k$ and the product of $t$ and $h$. To be honest, I'd typeset it as just `$k$th` -- one doesn't use a hyphen in "4th", for example.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I've seen $k$-th (or in plain text, k-th) any number of times; I think it's eminently clear from context, especially since $k$ appears as a variable but neither t nor h does, and since here $k$ is offset in math font while the others are plaintext.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I agree that "$k$-th" is common. I wouldn't describe it as wrong; just unnecessary when typesetting makes it clear that "$k$" is a variable and "th" denotes an ordinal (in the linguistic sense).

Comment: Cross-posted: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/65110/755, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1984522/14578. Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: @D.W. Origin post was deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking two questions. The first is an *enumeration* question, and the second is about *generation* or *encoding/decoding*. The enumeration question is a standard combinatorial exercise, which can be solved using exponential generating functions (and algorithmically, using dynamic programming). For example, the number of strings of length $\ell$ in your example is $\ell!$ times the coefficient of $x^\ell$ in the exponential generating function
$$
\left(1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!}\right)
\left(1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!}\right)^2
\left(1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!}\right).
$$

For the generation problem, the idea is as follows. Suppose that we want the $k$th lexciographically smallest string of length $\ell$. We will uncover the letters one by one. To find the first letter, we count how many strings of length $\ell$ start with each letter—an instance of the enumeration problem mentioned above—and use this information to determine the first letter. We find the subsequent letters in a very similar way.